# can't connect panda-es to HDMI/DVI display

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hdmi, pandaboard, dvi

I am getting the following pop up message on my monitor while connecting HDMI cable to panda to view console on my HDMI display.

> The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display.
>   Please change your timing to 1920x1080@60Hz or any other monitor
>   listed as per the monitor specifications.

my panda-es is running ubuntu 12.04.

How can change the output timings to match the display?
when i type fbset, i get the following output

```
mode "1920x1080"
     geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
     timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     accel true
     rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24 endmode
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never run Ubuntu on my PandaBoard, but depending on the kernel version you are using, on the omap display susbsystem driver, you may be able to change the timings:

Check here: [How to read and set EDID timings for HDMI](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootargs_for_enabling_display#How_to_read_and_set_EDID_timings_for_HDMI)

Also, have you installed the Texas Instrument addons and additional binaries? 
[Installing_OMAP4_Addons_via_Command_Line](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_PPA#Installing_OMAP4_Addons_via_Command_Line)